# Bootstrap Modal does not open on click

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a problem with the bootstrap modal function. 
I try to open a modal when clicking on a button. In Bootply everything works fine, but in my document it's not working and I can't see why.
I try to use the modal in the portfolio section of [this page](http://vickymawiva.bplaced.net/portfolio/keyframes.html)

Here is my code [snippet on bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lAtriPV9pj) which is perfectly working...
Any Ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look in for example Chrome's DevTools console you'll notice an error message like:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1
>   or higher

this either means that jQuery isn't loaded or that Bootstrap's JavaScript is loaded before jQuery.

If you take a look in your `head` section you'll see that the latter is the case. Make sure that `js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js` occurs before `js/bootstrap.min.js`.

**P.S.** it might be that the modal still doesn't work after these changes, but you need to fix this first.

Comment: Thank you! seems like I just havent seen this, but it was exaclty the problem here. Thank you a lot, now it's working.